# How do I delete certain files in the current directory that doesn't match the given pattern?

Tags: unix, shell, command-line, terminal

using `rm *.sh` to delete files ending in .sh is easy and understandable. But how do i delete all files in the current directory that does not end in `.jar`
something like `rm * -except *.jar`

Comment: Tag this question with [Bash]      =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 ! -name '*.jar' | sort
```

If you really want to delete all the files in its output, then just do

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 ! -name '*.jar' -delete
```

You can read the find(1) manual page for more information on this really powerful tool.

EDIT:

Since the -delete flag is only found in GNU find > 4.2.3 (as pointed out by SiegeX), here are a couple of alternatives, which also make sure we are not trying to delete directories:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 ! -type d ! -name '*.jar' -print0 | xargs -0 -r rm -f
```

The -r xargs flags is a GNU extension, so this is slightly more portable (it works on *BSD), but not as clean:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 ! -type d ! -name '*.jar' -print0 | xargs -0 rm -f
```

As a last - but most portable - resort:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 ! -type d ! -name '*.jar' -exec rm '{}' ';'
```

This has the disadvantage of invoking rm separately for each file, which makes it significantly slower.

Comment: the '-delete' flag seems to be non-standard.  I would recommend changing it to `-exec rm {} \;` or `-exec rm {} +`.  However, using `find` for this task is a bit like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut. Look at my answer that uses the shell's `extglob` options.

Comment: @SiegeX - of course, `extglob` is also non-standard (bash only) if you're concerned with that, and `ls` has problems with whitespace, so `find` is the only *portable* way (that I know) to do it.

Comment: I highly recommend using `-exec rm {} +` rather than piping to xargs. [It's also POSIX](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html)

Comment: The ...+ -exec variant did not exist in GNU findutils till 5 years ago and I still have systems from that long back. I really don't think we will easily find a oneliner that works _everywhere_. The best advice would probably be for the OP to Read The Fine Manual and find(1) out what works on their system.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $(ls | grep -v '.jar$')

rm $(ls | grep -v '.jar$')
```

Comment: What if some of the filenames contain whitespace?

Comment: Uh, doesn't this have some rather significant issues with whitespace in filenames?

Comment: @Gareth: heh... you were faster. Anyway I just verified (for my peace of mind, mostly) that this will NOT work if there is whitespace in the filenames

Comment: Parsing `ls` is one of the worst things you can do, parsing `ls` as means to remove a file or folder is the 2nd worst thing you can do. Read [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) to find out why.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by enabling the extended glob `extglob` option and then putting your pattern inside `!()` like so:

```
shopt -s extglob;
rm !(*.jar)
```

Note that `extglob` also gives you the following:

- `?()` -- Match zero or one of the pattern
- `*()` -- Match zero or more of the pattern
- `@()` -- Match exactly one of the pattern
- `!()` -- Match anything except the pattern

Comment: Only for Bash, ksh and zsh. The question is tagged `[shell]` so if he's using Bourne or C shell, this won't work.