#  Using find - Deleting all files/directories (in Linux ) except any one

Tags: linux, file, shell

If we want to delete all files and directories we use, `rm -rf *`.

But what if i want all files and directories be deleted at a shot, except one particular file?

Is there any command for that? `rm -rf *` gives the ease of deletion at one shot, but deletes even my favourite file/directory.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[`find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) can be a very good friend:

```
$ ls
a/  b/  c/
$ find * -maxdepth 0 -name 'b' -prune -o -exec rm -rf '{}' ';'
$ ls
b/
$
```

Explanation:

- `find * -maxdepth 0`: select everything selected by `*` without descending into any directories
- `-name 'b' -prune`: do not bother (`-prune`) with anything that matches the condition `-name 'b'`
- `-o -exec rm -rf '{}' ';'`: call `rm -rf` for everything else

By  the way, another, possibly simpler, way would be to move or rename your *favourite* directory so that it is not in the way:

```
$ ls
a/  b/  c/
$ mv b .b
$ ls
a/  c/
$ rm -rf *
$ mv .b b
$ ls
b/
```

Comment: It can be improved: `find * -maxdepth 0 -name 'b' -prune -o -exec rm -rf {} \;`

Comment: @maveric: agreed, that's how I'd write it, but I'd rather not get into the various shell intricacies involving quoting and escaping in this answer...

Comment: Could you not generate the list of files excluding the file to be "protected" and then pipe it to `xargs` rather than spawning `rm` for every match using `-exec`?

Comment: @Noufal: not portably - many `xargs` variants out there do not have `-0` which tends to make things easier when dealing with whitespace.

Comment: @Noufal: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4262108/507519) there is quite a bit of portability information in the comments.

Comment: `find *` is terrible. The `*` will be globbed by the shell, and in a crowded directory the number of items could exceed ARGV_MAX. Try to use `find .` whenever possible.

Comment: @wildplasser: that is true, although less likely with [modern Linux kernel versions](http://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_2_6_23#head-ae2a4a278f6bb0de179f59b3dfc3fbdb2b43bf01). That said, when writing this answer I tried to remain as close to the OP's `rm -rf *` as possible, while also avoiding introducing more conditions to protect `.` itself from deletion.

Comment: Note: there is no possible way to unlink `.`. Note 2: since filesystems can be larger than available memory, ARGV_MAX will always be a problem, waiting in the dark to strike unexpectedly. Avoid it. And finally: you don't **have to** _materialise_ a list if you can serialise/pipe it. (there will be a race condition in either cases, so that cannot be a reason to prefer one over the other)

Comment: The 2nd tip is awesome, I was looking to delete everything except the git files and that worked awesome

Answer (score 10):

**Short answer**

```
ls | grep -v "z.txt" | xargs rm
```

**Details**:

The thought process for the above command is :

- List all files (ls)
- Ignore one file named "z.txt" (grep -v "z.txt")
- Delete the listed files other than z.txt  (xargs rm)

Example

Create 5 files as shown below:

```
echo "a.txt b.txt c.txt d.txt z.txt" | xargs touch
```

List all files except z.txt

```
ls|grep -v "z.txt"

a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
d.txt
```

We can now delete(rm) the listed files by using the **xargs** utility :

```
ls|grep -v "z.txt"|xargs rm
```

Comment: Very elegant solution. Short and easy to understand. It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can type it right in the command-line or use this keystroke in the script

```
files=`ls -l | grep -v "my_favorite_dir"`; for file in $files; do rm -rvf $file; done
```

P.S. I suggest `-i` switch for `rm` to prevent delition of important data.

P.P.S You can write the small script based on this solution and place it to the `/usr/bin` (e.g. `/usr/bin/rmf`). Now you can use it as and ordinary app:

```
rmf my_favorite_dir
```

The script looks like (just a sketch):

```
#!/bin/sh

if [[ -z $1 ]]; then
    files=`ls -l`
else
    files=`ls -l | grep -v $1`
fi;

for file in $files; do
    rm -rvi $file
done;
```

Comment: Hmmm, [parsing the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) is not a good idea - it's a bad habit that should not be propagated to others. And your `for` loops will have issues with filenames that include whitespace...

Comment: Don't know. Thanks for the hint :)

Answer (score 2):

At least in zsh

```
rm -rf ^filename
```

could be an option, if you only want to preserve one single file.

Answer (score 1):

If it's just one file, one simple way is to move that file to `/tmp` or something, `rm -Rf` the directory and then move it back. You could alias this as a simple command.

The other option is to do a `find` and then `grep` out what you don't want (using `-v` or directly using one of `find`s predicates) and then `rm`ing the remaining files.

For a single file, I'd do the former. For anything more, I'd write something custom similar to what thkala said.

Answer (score 1):

In bash you have the `!()` glob operator, which inverts the matched pattern. So to delete everything except the file `my_file_name.txt`, try this:

```
shopt -s extglob
rm -f !(my_file_name.txt)
```

See this article for more details:
http://karper.wordpress.com/2010/11/17/deleting-all-files-in-a-directory-with-exceptions/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of such a program, but I have wanted it in the past for some times. The basic syntax would be:

```
IFS='
' for f in $(except "*.c" "*.h" -- *); do
  printf '%s\n' "$f"
done
```

The program I have in mind has three modes:

- exact matching (with the option `-e`)
- `glob` matching (default, like shown in the above example)
- regex matching (with the option `-r`)

It takes the patterns to be excluded from the command line, followed by the separator `--`, followed by the file names. Alternatively, the file names might be read from `stdin` (if the option `-s` is given), each on a line.

Such a program should not be hard to write, in either C or the Shell Command Language. And it makes a good excercise for learning the Unix basics. When you do it as a shell program, you have to watch for filenames containing whitespace and other special characters, of course.

Comment: What you are asking for is a simple wrapper for `find`

Comment: No, I want a general tool. Maybe I want to `cp` some files except for `.svn`, maybe I want to echo their names. The problem with `find` is that it doesn't know the `-maxdepth` option on all systems. See  http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html.

Answer (score 0):

I see a lot of longwinded means here, that work, but with 
a/ b/ c/ d/ e/

```
 rm -rf *.* !(b*)
```

this removes everything except directory b/ and its contents (assuming your file is in b/.
Then just cd b/ and

```
rm -rf *.* !(filename)
```

to remove everything else, but the file (named "filename") that you want to keep.

Answer (score 0):

```
mv subdir/preciousfile  ./
rm -rf subdir
mkdir subdir
mv preciousfile subdir/
```

This looks tedious, but it is rather safe

- avoids complex logic
- never use `rm -rf *`, its results depend on your current directory (which could be `/` ;-)
- never use a globbing `*`: its expansion is limited by ARGV_MAX.
- allows you to check the error after each command, and maybe avoid the disaster caused by the next command.
- avoids nasty problems caused by space or NL in the filenames.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd ..
ln trash/useful.file ./
rm -rf trash/*
mv useful.file trash/
```

Comment: NB: This won't work across file system boundaries. e.g. if `trash` is on a different file system to `.`

Comment: Dezza, I have never thought about it in this context... Anyway, now I know what 'nota bene' is :)

Answer (score -1):

you need to use regular expression for this. Write a regular expression which selects all other files except the one you need.

Comment: Regular expressions are *one* way to do it but you don't *need* them.

Comment: Regular expressions fed into *what*? Most shells only use simple glob expressions.